# Could a Raspberry PI 2 with a RTOS read about 18 MBytes/s of data by GPIO?

Tags: gpio, video

Do you think a Raspberry Pi 2 with a RTOS be able to perform a VGA input with ADC used on GPIO ? Well, I didn't found many documentation saying if GPIOs of the Raspberry Pi 2 are faster than the Raspberry Pi 1.

So I wanted to know if the Raspberry Pi could read at least 18 432 000 Bytes per second on 3 GPIO ( 640 * 480 * 60 Hz VGA ) with an ADC like the [TVP7002](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tvp7002.pdf) from TI and be able to react to the sync signals ? If not, do you think a board like the BeagleBone who has PRUs could do this ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The camera interface presumably has the bandwidth, if you can reformat the data.  And slower but architecturally simpler ARM MCU's could do it, so leave the hardware question aside for the moment.  What will you do with the data?  Save it?  Compress it as video?  Those will be challenges of their own.  If you merely want to do a static image capture, then capturing only a small part of each of many frames could be an option, potentially even with the GPIOs if you can use a hardware timer to trigger the capture.

Comment: It would be to send the video to another computer by Ethernet (the simplest I think). I need at least to do a static image capture (I don't need 60 fps) and send it by Ethernet to remote control any computer with a vga output without any software by an Arduino. This is at least what I need. After, I have plenty of ideas of what I'll do if I could stream high resolution video with a good framerate, but to begin if I can have a single picture at low resolution every seconds it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the Raspberry Pi gpios can be toggled at more than 30 million bits per second (the Pi model is irrelevant for all the BCM2835/BCM2836 based Pis).

So theoretically 3.75 MBps from each gpio.  That should be enough to show you it's a non-starter on the Raspberry Pi.

I'd say it's a non-starter on the BeagleBone as well but look forward to being proved wrong.

Comment: Well, it's what I thought, I knew than the Raspberry Pi 1 gpio cannot handle so much data from each gpio but I hoped than the Raspberry Pi 2 could do this. I will ask on a BeagleBone forum if the PRU who could do bitbanging to 200 MHz could do this.